# cannot replace factor variable within a list r

Tags: r, list

I have the following list of dataframes structure:

```
str(mylist)

List of 2
 $ L1   :'data.frame':   12471 obs. of 3 variables:
 ...$ colA : Date[1:12471], format: "2006-10-10" "2010-06-21" ...
 ...$ colB : int [1:12471], 62 42 55 12 78 ...
 ...$ colC : Factor w/ 3 levels "type1","type2","type3",..: 1 2 3 2 2 ...
```

I would like to replace `type1` or `type2` with a new factor `type4`.

I have tried:

```
mylist <- lapply(mylist, transform, colC =
                       replace(colC, colC == 'type1','type4'))
Warning message:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "type4") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "type4") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I do not want to read in my initial data with `stringAsFactor=F` but i have tried adding `type4` as a level in my initial dataset (before splitting into a list of dataframes) using:

```
levels(mydf$colC) <- c(levels(mydf$colC), "type4")
```

but I still get the same error when trying to replace.

how do I tell replace that `type4` is to be treated as a factor?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `levels` options to renew your factor.
Such as,

`status <- factor(status, order=TRUE, levels=c("1", "3", "2",...))`

`c("1", "3", "2",...)` is your `type4` in here.

Answer (score 0):

As you state, the crucial thing is to add the new factor level.

```
## Test data:
mydf <- data.frame(colC = factor(c("type1", "type2", "type3",  "type2", "type2")))
mylist <- list(mydf, mydf)
```

Your data has three factor levels:

```
> str(mylist)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ colC: Factor w/ 3 levels "type1","type2",..: 1 2 3 2 2
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ colC: Factor w/ 3 levels "type1","type2",..: 1 2 3 2 2
```

Now add the fourth factor level, then your `replace` command should work:

```
## Change levels:
for (ii in seq(along = mylist)) levels(mylist[[ii]]$colC) <- 
    c(levels(mylist[[ii]]$colC), "type4")

## Replace level:
mylist <- lapply(mylist, transform, colC = replace(colC, 
    colC == 'type1','type4'))
```

The new data has four factor levels:

```
> str(mylist)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ colC: Factor w/ 4 levels "type1","type2",..: 4 2 3 2 2
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ colC: Factor w/ 4 levels "type1","type2",..: 4 2 3 2 2
```